# WPF Combobox is not updating when collection changed in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

WPF `Combobox` is not updating when collection changed in `Model`.

I am using `ICollectionView` for both DataGrid and ComboBox. DataGrid is updating when collection is changed in model, but ***ComboBox is not updating***. Please let me know if there are any alternate ways to do this.

Here is the code

Model->
In Model I have

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> MyModelProducts
```

ViewModel->
DataGrid Collection

```
public ICollectionView MyViewModelProducts
{
  get 
  {   
    return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyModel.Instance.MyModelProducts);             
  }
}
```

ViewModel-ComboBox Collection

```
public ICollectionView MyViewModelListOfProducts
{
  get 
  {   
    return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyModel.Instance.MyModelProducts.Select(p => p.Category).Distinct().ToList<string>());            
  }
}
```

Code in View-->

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelListOfProducts, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Binding MyViewModelProducts to DataGrid

Binding MyViewModelListOfProducts to a ComboBox.

Comment: Have you tried binding the combo to the datagrid

Comment: My ComboBox is outside the DataGrid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to refer to the selected product in offer to filter
2. Set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true in the `DataGrid`.
3. Raise a property change of `MyViewModelListOfProducts` when you want it to update. You subscribe the the `MyViewModelProducts.CurrentChanged` event and update it from there.
4. You can have a property `DistinctCategories` or so in the `Product` class that does that linq query (and is notified upon change, of course), and then bind the `ComboBox` to the `MyViewModelProducts` and point to this property - this I think is the preferred way, unless you think the distinct categories is has really no use in the model layer.